Use array data with zip in python
i have some worked code with python
golden_gate_park = zip(*[
    (55.87694550, 37.48297183),
    (55.87870300, 37.48198183),
    (55.87875750, 37.48202100),
    (55.87880417, 37.48206183),
    (55.87883250, 37.48209700),
    (55.87979000, 37.48279567),
    (55.87993383, 37.48277550),
    (55.88843017, 37.48345133),
    (55.89800350, 37.48674450),
    (55.89821033, 37.48673800)
])

it is gps coordinates
and i have array:
array = ['55.87694550 37.48297183', '55.87870300 37.48198183', '55.87875750 37.48202100', '55.87880417 37.48206183', '55.87883250 37.48209700', '55.87979000 37.48279567', '55.87993383 37.48277550', '55.88843017 37.48345133', '55.89800350 37.48674450', '55.89821033 37.48673800', '55.89841483 37.48671867', '55.89861500 37.48668800', '55.89881033 37.48664517']

how can i use array values in golden_gate_park zip?
i can use only one value:
mapcoord1 = array[0].split(" ")[0]
mapcoord2 = array[0].split(" ")[1]
attractions_lats, attractions_lngs =  zip(*{
    (float(mapcoord1), float(mapcoord2)),

})

but i need all data from array

Relatively important technical note: Python does not have arrays, it has lists, and you are showing a list. And then on a programming note: don't call your variables based on their datatype (in part because it's just bad practice but also because that leads to hilarious bugs where you overwrite built-ins because your variable now "shadows" them), call them after what they contain/represent, so that others reading your code understand what you're trying to do from the code itself.

Why are yuo zipping when you create golden_gate_park? Algorithms are usually easier when you keep related data together. So keep lat and long for each point together in a tuple, rather than making separate lists of lat and long.

You can convert the list to a list of tuples with float values and unzip the coordinates into latitude and longitude like this-
array = [
    '55.87694550 37.48297183',
    '55.87870300 37.48198183',
    '55.87875750 37.48202100',
    '55.87880417 37.48206183',
    '55.87883250 37.48209700',
    '55.87979000 37.48279567',
    '55.87993383 37.48277550',
    '55.88843017 37.48345133',
    '55.89800350 37.48674450',
    '55.89821033 37.48673800',
    '55.89841483 37.48671867',
    '55.89861500 37.48668800',
    '55.89881033 37.48664517'
]

coordinates = [tuple(map(float, coord.split())) for coord in array]
attractions_lats, attractions_lngs = zip(*coordinates)

print(f"{coordinates=}")
print(f"{attractions_lats=}")
print(f"{attractions_lngs=}")

# If you want to use them in golden_gate_park
golden_gate_park = zip(attractions_lats, attractions_lngs)

# Print the zipped coordinates
for coord in golden_gate_park:
    print(coord)


don't call lists arrays =(

Sorry, I forget and messed up between my php+js and python knowledge

@RADIOBUTIK you can mark it as an answer then with green tick ✅
